# Mootools Unity3D import

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm having problems importing and displaying an Unity3D web-application with mootools.

With jQuery I was able to do this, but it seems like without using jQuery an UnityObject2 could not be created?

Anyone has a solution for this?

Here some code:

```
alert($('content'));
        $('content').set("html",'<div id="unityPlayer">\
            <div class="missing">\
                <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">\
                    <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />\
                </a>\
            </div>\
            <div class="broken">\
                <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install.">\
                    <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install." src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunityrestart.png" width="193" height="63" />\
                </a>\
            </div>\
        </div>');
        var config = {
            width: croppedWidth, 
            height: croppedHeight,
            params: { enableDebugging:"0" }
        };
        var u = new UnityObject2(config);
        u.initPlugin($('unityPlayer'), "3D/login.unity3d");
```

Kind regards!

Comment: do you actually get any errors? does it produce the correct markup? is `$('content')` in the DOM? do you have croppedWidth/Height defined? unless you can build a prototype of this on jsfiddle, it's hard to really help.

Comment: that why i alerted alert($('content'))... it exists, doing this u = new UnityObject2(config) returns NULL - here is the problem. croppedWidth and croppedHeight is set and working. It has something to do that UnityObject2() was written in jQuery. I need an alternative for plain javascript / Mootools NOT using jQuery.

Comment: hrm you could try the mootools backbone adapter, which mocks a lot of the jquery func that backbone uses: https://github.com/inkling/backbone-mootools/ - you may get lucky. else, you need to mimick the style and possibly post the source code of the UnityObject2 constructor so at least the jquery calls can be identified.